# C# extension method for setting to new instance if null

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have the following extension methods to help me check and instantiate objects if they are null. The top two work just fine but they are not very useful.

```
    public static bool IsNull<T>(this T t)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(t, null);
    }

    public static T NewIfNull<T>(this T t, Func<T> createNew)
    {
        if (t.IsNull<T>())
        {
            return createNew();
        }

        return t;
    }

    public static void Ensure<T>(this T t, Func<T> createNew)
    {
        t = t.NewIfNull<T>(createNew);
    }
```

Ultimately I would like to do something like

```
IList<string> foo;
...
foo.Ensure<IList<string>>(() => new List<string>());
```

The Ensure method however does not achieve the desired effect, which is setting `foo` to a instance of `List<string>` if it is null and basically set it to itself otherwise.

if you know now I can tweak the Ensure method to achieve this I would appreciate the help.

Thanks, Tom

Comment: You'd need to use a "ref" modifier on the "this T t" parameter/argument to achieve what you want, which is not supported in C#. Also, code using null coalescing will probably be easier to read than this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to distinguish between *objects* and *variables*. An object can never be null - the value of a variable can be. You're not trying to change something about an object (which *would* work) - you're trying to change the value of the caller's variable.

However, arguments are passed by value by default, which means that your extension method changes the *parameter* (the variable declared within the method), but this has no effect on the *caller's* variable. Normally you'd be able to change the parameter to `ref` to achieve pass-by-reference semantics, but extension methods can't have a `ref` or `out` first parameter.

As others have said, using the [null-coalescing operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is a better bet. Note that in this expression:

```
foo = foo ?? new List<string>();
```

the new list is *not* constructed unless `foo` is null. The right hand operand of `??` is not evaluated unless it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

So you're attempting to duplicate the [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator?

```
foo = foo ?? new List<string>();
```

Comment: "you cannot call a method on `null`" You cannot call true instance methods, but you *can* call extension methods on `null`. That said I don't see the point of using extension methods either...

Answer (score 1):

Your `Ensure` method doesn't work because you're just setting a local reference variable (`t`) but *not returning it*. If `Ensure` returned `t`, you could do:

```
var list2 = list1.Ensure<List<string>>();
```

However, you don't need that because you can just use the ?? operator:

```
var list2 = list1 ?? new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Ensure` method does not do anything because assigning something new to a parameter `t` does not change anything for the caller when `t` is not a `ref` (or `out`) parameter. Instead, saying

```
IList<string> foo;
...
foo = foo.NewIfNull(() => new List<string>());
```

will probably work, but as others have said isn't the most beautiful way of doing this.