# using helper method to create an instance of "this"

Tags: c#, helper

i have this code;

```
public static void SetMyClass (this myClass data, ListControl crl) 
{
    var value = crl.SelectedValue.ToNullableInt();

    if (value.HasValue)
    {
        data = new myClass () { Id = value.Value };
    }
}
```

this code doesn't change the original instance by the new one.

can this be done?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Check this question and Jon's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967421/c-sharp-extension-method-for-setting-to-new-instance-if-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to keep the helper I will be using this instead

```
public static T GetMyClass<T>(this ListControl data) where T : myClass, new()
{
    var value = data.SelectedValue.ToNullableInt();

    if (value.HasValue)
    {

        return new T() { Id = value.Value };
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void SetMyClass (ref myClass data, ListControl crl) 
{
    var value = crl.SelectedValue.ToNullableInt();

    if (value.HasValue)
    {
        data = new myClass () { Id = value.Value };
    }
}
```

You loose the extension method but gain the ability to alter the reference inside the method.

The same with an extension method is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done because you need to pass your parameter by reference instead of value which requires using the `ref` keyword... And extension methods do not support `ref` for the first parameter (the instance parameter).

Why not just set `data`s property to the value?